# Best DataType for my Table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sqldatatypes

I am at loss in datatype selection of table below in sqlite. Columns highlighted yellow are user inputs while rest are calculated fields. Screenshot display a spreadsheet not sqlite table!
[image]

From the knowledge I gained it's said that datatype selection (to a measurable extent) influence values of calculated fields.

For instance I make a sqlite table `ELZ_A` where all input fields are besides DATE towards left & all calculated fields towards right. If then I add `triggers`

```
UPDATE ELZ_A SET CURRENT_DENSITY = ROUND((LOAD / 2.721), 2);
UPDATE ELZ_A SET VOLTS_AVG = ROUND((VOLTS_T / ELEMENTS), 2);
UPDATE ELZ_A SET VOLTS_STNDR = ROUND(2.4 + ((12.75 / 2.721) * ((VOLTS_AVG - 2.4) / CURRENT_DENSITY) - ((90 - CATHOLYTE_TEMP) * 0.01) + ((32 - CATHOLYTE_CONC) * 0.02)), 4);
UPDATE ELZ_A SET KF_FACTOR = ROUND(((VOLTS_AVG - (90 - CATHOLYTE_TEMP) * 0.016 * ((LOAD / 2.721) / 5)) + ((32 - CATHOLYTE_CONC) * 0.033 * ((LOAD / 2.721) / 5) - 2.4)) / (LOAD / 2.721), 4);
```

As one can see calculated field `VOLTS_STNDR` is further used to calculate `KF_FACTOR` also I am rounding first two results upto 2 places while the latter upto 4...So how I can assure using data-type best suited for displayed data to get precise calculated answers akin to that what EXCEL calculates

---

**Problem Explained Further @SQLite Studio v3.0.6 @Debian x32**

All of my columns contains decimals except Elements (which are whole numbers) so I am using ...till `EFFICIENCY` are user inputs further are calculated columns.
[image]

Now I am having this problem
[image]
As one can observe where `EFFICIENCY` is a whole number productions becomes zero?? So why is this problem. Problem is mitigated by tuning DataTypes such as
[image]
[image]
...but this is further confusing, as I cannot comprehend the actual cause

Comment: A SQL view can calculate the computed data while acting as a normal table. When you store computed values in actual tables, you run the risk of your computed data not matching the source data.

Comment: ..not matching source data, this isn't possible unless your query end up with a corrupted .db

Comment: Sure it's possible: `INSERT INTO some_table(x, x_plus_two) VALUES (15, 16); UPDATE some_table SET x = 3 WHERE x = 5 /* oops forgot to update x_plus_two */;`

Comment: I have explained my problem further, please revisit question

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), so what data type you declare does not matter for the DB itself.

In Excel, numbers are always stored with maximum precision; the formatting settings influence only how they are displayed.
So to get maximum accuracy, drop all ROUND() calls, and change the code that displays the data.

And calculated fields are best implemented with a view.